# I get a null reference error on the line where I use Name

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var category = await _companyContext.PRODUCTCATEGORIES.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == categoryId && (bool)p.STATE);

            category.NAME = name;
            category.WORKPLACEID = workplaceid;
            _companyContext.Update(category);
```

> My problem is in the line with NAME

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return either an instance or null.
Therefore, you should always check the return value for null e.g.,

```
var category = await _companyContext.PRODUCTCATEGORIES.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == categoryId && (bool)p.STATE);

if(category!=NULL)
{
        category.NAME = name;
        category.WORKPLACEID = workplaceid;
        _companyContext.Update(category);
}
```

Without the full exception text being posted I suspect that `category == NULL` is true